# Primefaces selectOneListbox not displaying item text (nor is the data contained in the items)

Tags: primefaces

My PrimeFaces selectOneListbox has 3000 items in it - as can be seen from the object inspector in chrome's debugger.  The div rows are all there, but there's no data in them for display text.  The divs are all empty.

I double checked and the itemValue points to the company.name which has data in it.  Also, the itemLabel gets the unique symbol for the company, so that should be fine too, because that data is all valid.  However, I've missed something because the UI shows a blank box and is visibly taller than its empty default - and as I said, contains the 3000 empty items in the form of empty divs in chrome's debugger.

The code in my xhtml for the selectOneListbox is the following.  I've tried a map as a collection and a list in my managed bean (so I changed the value to whichever variable I wanted to try).  Both the map and the list of companies yielded the same results - a list of 3000 entries in the javascript (shown below)

```
<p:selectOneListbox id="symbolPicker" value="#{simulationBean.company}" converter="companyConverter" var="t" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">
    <f:selectItems value="#{simulationBean.companyMap}" var="company" itemLabel="#{company.symbol}" itemValue="#{company}" />
</p:selectOneListbox>
```

The javascript of the empty items:

[image: Pic of chrome debugger]

The managed bean just stores a list of companies that are all obviously initialized @PostConstruct, because the objects are being enumerated (3000 of them) in my debugger - so the companies are there and their data is valid (I can see the data in the debugger).

And I'm guessing the culprit will be in this next object. I can't imagine what I'm missing - it seems it must be really obvious - here's the company entity itself:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String symbol;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column(columnDefinition="market_category")
    private String marketCategory;

    @Column(columnDefinition="test_issue")
    private Integer testIssue;

    @Column(columnDefinition="good_status")
    private Integer goodStatus;

    @Column(columnDefinition="round_lot")
    private Integer roundLot;

    @Column
    private Integer etf;

    public Company() {}

    public Company(String symbol, String name, String marketCategory, Integer testIssue, Integer goodStatus, Integer roundLot, Integer etf) {
        super();
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.name = name;
        this.marketCategory = marketCategory;
        this.testIssue = testIssue;
        this.goodStatus = goodStatus;
        this.roundLot = roundLot;
        this.etf = etf;
    }

    @Id
    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMarketCategory() {
        return marketCategory;
    }

    public void setMarketCategory(String marketCategory) {
        this.marketCategory = marketCategory;
    }

    public Integer getTestIssue() {
        return testIssue;
    }

    public void setTestIssue(Integer testIssue) {
        this.testIssue = testIssue;
    }

    public Integer getGoodStatus() {
        return goodStatus;
    }

    public void setGoodStatus(Integer goodStatus) {
        this.goodStatus = goodStatus;
    }

    public Integer getRoundLot() {
        return roundLot;
    }

    public void setRoundLot(Integer roundLot) {
        this.roundLot = roundLot;
    }

    public Integer getEtf() {
        return etf;
    }

    public void setEtf(Integer etf) {
        this.etf = etf;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public String toDebugString() {
        return "Company [symbol=" + symbol + ", name=" + name + ", marketCategory=" + marketCategory + ", testIssue="
                + testIssue + ", goodStatus=" + goodStatus + ", roundLot=" + roundLot + ", etf=" + etf + "]";
    }

    @Transient
    public JsonObject getJsonObject() {

        JsonObject result = new JsonObject();

        result.addProperty("symbol", symbol);
        result.addProperty("name", name);
        result.addProperty("marketCategory", marketCategory);
        result.addProperty("testIssue", testIssue);
        result.addProperty("goodStatus", goodStatus);
        result.addProperty("roundLot", roundLot);
        result.addProperty("etf", etf);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        // null check
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }

        // this instance check
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }

        // instanceof Check and actual value check
        if ((obj instanceof Company) && (((Company) obj).getSymbol() == this.symbol)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return symbol.hashCode();
    }
}
```

And now I have a converter as well:

```
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

import com.appzany.stockService.BeanUtil;
import com.appzany.stockService.entity.Company;
import com.appzany.stockService.stockservice.StockService;

@FacesConverter("companyConverter")
public class CompanyConverter implements Converter {

    private StockService stockService = null;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {

        if(stockService == null)
            stockService = BeanUtil.getBean(StockService.class);
        return stockService.getCompany(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return ((Company)value).getSymbol();
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't going to fix your problem but a couple of things I would do is make your Entity a Serializable object and also implement a good Equals(), HashCode() methods.

Comment: Oh I think that's got to be the problem actually!  I'll bet that's it!!!

Comment: You were right - it didn't fix the problem. I updated the question to include your suggestions in my entity though.  Thanks!

Comment: From this page, I'm missing the converter:  https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/listbox.xhtml, but I don't have a converter as they do (converter="themeConverter") - no idea how to create it for my example because this "themeConverter" is not found anywhere in the example they provide.

Comment: Creating a converter is easy. See this tutorial: https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/

Comment: What's the converter for exactly - every example I've seen show how to do it, but I can't see how it fits in with the selectOneListBox?  It's an optional parameter - is this the reason my item text isn't showing up?

Comment: The listbox gets `itemValue="#{company.name}"`. I think you can't `<h:outputText value="#{t.symbol}" />` out of this value. Propably you should use `itemValue="#{company}"` and a converter. Because, itemLabel is already `itemLabel="#{company.symbol}"` you don't need another `<h:outputText value="#{t.symbol}" />`.

Comment: The `value` of the listbox should be of same typ as the `value` of `<f:selectItems`

Comment: @Holger, I updated the question with your suggestions.  I added the converter, dropped the <h:outputText>, and now the value of the listbox is same as <f:selectItems> - they are both a company. Thanks for your help- those do make sense, unfortunately, I still get empty items.

Comment: Start by comparing your code with the PrimeFaces showcase. Simplify your code (also for an [mcve], remove the var and var on both tags and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be wanting to use the 'Advanced' p:selectOneListbox which in [their showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/listbox.xhtml) is as follows

```
<p:selectOneListbox id="advanced" value="#{selectOneView.theme}" converter="themeConverter" var="t" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">

    <f:selectItems value="#{selectOneView.themes}" var="theme" itemLabel="#{theme.displayName}" itemValue="#{theme}" />

    <p:column>
        <h:graphicImage name="showcase/images/themeswitcher/themeswitcher-#{t.name}.png" alt="#{t.name}" styleClass="ui-theme" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{t.displayName}" />
    </p:column>
</p:selectOneListbox>
```

Where both the `p:selectOneListbox` and the `f:selectItems` have a var attribute of which the var attribute of the `p:selectOneListbox` is being used in explicit additional tags inside this component. These additional `p:column` tags and their content take care of the 'advanced' rendering. You don't have any of this, which I think (sorry, did not try) results in rendering 'nothing'. If you'd add something to render like

```
<p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{t.name}" />
</p:column>

<p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{t.symbol}" />
</p:column>
```

I'm sure something IS rendered.

Comment: Darn, I had removed the columns before adding the converter.  Forgot I had done that - so forgot to put them back in.  Thanks!!